# iphone zoom out on select drop down

Tags: iphone, cordova

On select of a list from select drop down, the UI was getting zoomed-in on iphone.
I googled a bit and found solution which solved the problem, see below for solution:

```
<select style="font-size:16px;"></select>
```

Problem: when the user zooms-in the UI and taps on select list, the UI resizes to original
size whereas the same is not true when the user taps on some other button.

Thanks in advance,

TheIlliterate